# Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на одно изображение менялось другое?

Tags: css

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наведении на большой блок изображения (красно-белый), менялась бы картинка круга (которая внутри) на другое изображение круга.

Вот, для наглядности, какой эффект я хочу получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Скорее всего это можно сделать через тильду, но у меня не получилось.

Comment: для начала следует выложить свой код, с которым есть проблемы

Comment: Как вариант - можно прикрутить JS, что при наведении (hover) на блок менять картинку. Но присоединюсь к комментарию выше - требуется код, с которым уже работать.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу два варианта. 
 1. Весь этот блок красно белый имеет в качестве бэкграунда картинку с этим кругом в центре. При наведении менять картинку (а лучше использовать спрайт и менять смещение фона).

```
  .block{
       background:#fff url('someimage.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
   }
   .block:hover{
       background-position:0 100%;
   }
```

2. Большой блок имеет постоянный фон, а внутри него блок содержащий изменяемый фон

.

```
.block{
   background:#fff url('someimage.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 }
 .block .inblock{
   background:#fff url('someimage2.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
 }
.block:hover .inblock{
    background-position:0 100%;
 }
```